# Cannot create URL in application support directory for caf file 

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, caf

When I write this code it work will

```
    NSString *recordFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: (NSString*)inRecordFile];    

    NSLog(@"////////////////////////// recordFile /////////////////////");
    NSLog(recordFile) ;
    url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, NULL);

    // create the audio file
    XThrowIfError(AudioFileCreateWithURL(url, kAudioFileCAFType, &mRecordFormat, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                      &mRecordFile), "AudioFileCreateWithURL failed");
    CFRelease(url);
```

but when I change recordFile  to be such that

```
NSString* Dpath ; 
NSArray * paths;

// Build the Directory 

paths  = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

Dpath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

Dpath = [DICOMpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YYYYYYYYYYYY"];

Dpath = [DICOMpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[FirstDirectory stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]] ;

Dpath = [DICOMpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[SecondtDirectory stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

Dpath = [DICOMpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XXX"];
NSString *recordFile = [Dpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:inRecordFile];
```

I see the message AudioFileCreateWithURL failed in the console, what's wrong in my code, am sure that the path I use in the second code exists , and work , inRecordFile is the caf file name

Comment: You are overwriting `Dpath` value from scratch every time. Is that what you really intend?

Comment: yes I want to get the full path , the problem in creating the caf file in this directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *documentFolderPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *mainImageFolderPath=[documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Audio"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:mainImageFolderPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:mainImageFolderPath
                              withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                               attributes:nil
                                                    error:NULL];
}
    NSDateFormatter *nameFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [nameFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSString *nameString = [nameFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [nameFormatter release];
    NSString *AudioPath = [mainImageFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf",nameString]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordedFile.caf"] toPath:AudioPath error:&error];
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Error audio %@", [error description]);
    else{
        [self.notifier voiceAdded:AudioPath];
        self.recordPath = AudioPath;
        containsSound = YES;
    }
```

Why are you going in more complexity? just when ur sound is recorded, copy caf file to your desired directory.